# JLabel keeps moving depending on values inside

Tags: java, swing, applet, jlabel

So I'm creating a Java Applet for a game, and I'm using a JLabel to show the current score of the player. The score inside the JLabel updates continuously, however when the score gets from 9 to 10 or 99 to 100, because of the added integer, the position of the JLabel (? or maybe just the text of the JLabel) gets moved.

For instance,

Score: 9      becomes 
   Score: 10

As you can see, the positioning of the word "Score" gets shifted to the left. I want to prevent this from happening. I thought that left-aligning the text would solve the problem, but it definitely hasn't. :/

Here's some relevant code:

```
label = new JLabel("Score", SwingConstants.LEFT);
label.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 27));
label.setText("Score: " + getScore());
label.setBounds(0, 152, 213, 42);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should all depend on the layout managers you're using and how you add your components to the containers, something you haven't told us. Oh, avoid setting the bounds of anything for that way lies danger.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels  I have a null layout... I'm not quite sure which was the best layout to use. Suggestions/Clarifications? Thanks.

Comment: @minoue10: There is no one "best layout to use". I suggest that you read the layout manager tutorial to learn about all of them. Often we nest layouts by using multiple JPanels, each with its own layout, nested in each other.

Comment: Why are you using JLabel at all, why dont you use paint(Graphics g){} method in your JApplet class, and g.setColor(Color.BLACK); g.drawString("text",x,y); to set text.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
label.setText("Score: " + getScore());
```

by:

```
label.setText(String.format("Score: %-5s", getScore()));
```

Where `5` means the maximum digits of the score. A negative number aligns to left, otherwise, aligns to right.

Answer (score 0):

try using

> label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
>
> label.setPreferredSize(new Dimmension(100,100));

had a pretty similar Problem, and as I wrote them together as Attributes for this Components, they were working prett well.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about your layout manager.  See this example.  Read up on layout managers to learn other ways to go about this.  Uncomment to prevent the label from moving.

```
public class Test
{
    private static int score = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));      

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Score: " + score);
        //panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(8));
        panel.add(label);
        //panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                score++;
                label.setText("Score: " + score);
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100);
    }
}
```